# How do i properly insert a tag? SQL

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

example

```
tag  { id PK, name TEXT };
item { id PK, exampleData LONG, tagId LONG //or foreign key depending on provider }
```

i'm using SQLite and C#. Is it proper to

1. Start a transaction
2. Insert into tag
3. If affected rows = 0 do a select to get tag.PK otherwise use last_insert_rowid
4. Insert item

or will there be a problem with the above? I plan to switch to MySql or TSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally insert the tag if it doesn't exist like:

```
insert into tag (name)
select 'NewTagName'
where not exists (select * from tag where name = 'NewTagName')
```

Then, while inserting the new item, you can query the tag id:

```
insert into item (exampleData, tagid)
select 'NewData', (select id from tag where name = 'NewTagName')
```

This method doesn't require retrieving the id of the inserted row, and will work fine without a transaction.

Comment: Or more briefly: "select 'NewData', id from tag where name = 'NewTagName'"

Comment: accepted because this help me write my query and also you didnt say to select first which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I would generally prefer :

1. Start a transaction
2. `select from tag` to determine whether the tag was already existing
3. if not existing, then `insert into tag`, and get the generated id *(checking if the insert worked, of course)*
4. i`nsert into item`
5. commit transaction *(or rollback if there was an error)*

The only difference with what your suggested is that I try to select from tag before trying to insert. Why ? Because I prefer not doing an insert that will most likely fail -- at least, if I have an UNIQUE index on the tag's name *(and you probably should)*.

But it will probably not change much...

Comment: I forgot to write that in, yes it is unique. But i was told to never select first because it isnt a write op and another transaction can insert it after i do my select causing either a insert failure (unique) or incorrect logic from having another copy

Comment: @acidzombie24: But the transaction will protect you from that. Imagine if you were writing a banking application. To transfer money from my account to your account, I must `select` the available balance first. If `balance >= transfer_amount` then do the transfer, otherwise don't. The same applies for your case.

Comment: Actually no it doesnt. I wrote a test case and it fails. http://www.pastie.org/757356 stick this into a winform project (web seems to crash on me when i try this). There is no race condition thanks to Semaphore and as you can see the results are 6 instead of 7. And they are both in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see with your design is that each item can only have 1 tag. Was that your intention?

Otherwise, your insertion procedure is fine. You just need to check if the tag already exists, as Pascal Martin suggested.

Comment: Nice catch on the single tag. Usually i allow multiple but in this case i am not using tags and was unsure of how i should insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no wrong with your solution i believe its correct and use it

but when you change to MySql or TSql
use the same solution

1- insert first 
2- return @@identity "ID" of the inserted row 
.....